# How to generate a .lib with Dev-cpp?

Tags: c++, dll, lib

I would like to generate a sqlite3.lib and sqlite3.dll for a project but with Dev-cpp the output files are sqlite3.a and sqlite3.dll.

My question is : how to generate a *.lib file with Dev-Cpp?

I used this link : http://source.online.free.fr/Windows_HowToCompileSQLite

Answer (score 1):

You have the .a files on Unix systems. These are simple archives of object files (.o).

On Windows, the alternative are .lib files, which are the same thing, but for Windows instead of Unix.

One thing you can try is simply renaming the file, changing the suffix from .a to .lib.